# How to import variables from a class to a new module and re-import the new values to the class?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm refactoring a huge code that I have and trying to organize it in different modules. I have this huge complex of strings and variables inside a class function that works perfectly, but I'd like to take it out from the class and import it from another .py file. The strings and variables are needed for the creation of a .txt file which is important for a software I'm using. The variables between the strings are defined inside the class, and how to take out them and put into another file and import it back to the class is not being very intuitive. So this is the question: How can I do it?

This is a code I'm using to calibrate a model software by trial and error. I've tried to think on solutions but it's not a very intuitive problem, as I'm trying to import variables that are supposed to already exist in the main code.

This is the class (in short):

```py
    class run_trial_and_error(object):
        def start_software(self):
            txtfile = '
                        GRID         NWB     NBR     IMX     KMX   NPROC  CLOSEC
         '+self.parameter['NWB']+' '+self.parameter['NBR']
                        '
```

This was done in a way that file would follow the softare's txt format (columns of 8 characters right-justified)
The variable self.parameter is a dictionary which contains the values randomly generated to be inputted correctly inside the txt.

Again, I'm not sure how to take the "txtfile" variable to another .py file and still use the generated values inside self.parameter. and import it again to the run_trial_and_error class.

As said before, the code is working perfectly. All I wanted is to refactorate and reorganize it for the sake of publishing into public repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it sounds like you just want to use one of the numerous format strings (imported from another file).

```
>>> parameters = {
...     'NWB': 132,
...     'NBR': 456,
... }
>>> 'some text %s %s' % (parameters['NWB'], parameters['NBR'])
'some text 132 456'
>>> 'some text %(NWB)s %(NBR)s' % parameters
'some text 132 456'
>>> 'some text {} {}'.format(parameters['NWB'], parameters['NBR'])
'some text 132 456'
>>> 'some text {NWB} {NBR}'.format(**parameters)
'some text 132 456'
```

Comment: Yes! You are correct! Anyway, I'd like to use the self.parameter, which is within run_trial_and_error class, to compose the txtfile variable which will be in another .py file and, further, use the txtfile var inside of the class again.

I may be honest and say that I'm not sure if I addressed the question correctly, because this come-and-go is really non-intuitive to me. Still I think that it d be a better solution than continuing using it inside the class (which is almost 2000 lines long because of the txtfile variable).